# To use CSOD (Cornerstone OnDemand) SOAP API, how to generate HMACSHA1 signature?

Tags: soap

I'm trying to use CSOD (Cornerstone OnDemand) LMS's SOAP API for catalog search. The authentication process requires a HMACSHA1 signature, which should be generated based on a HMACSHA1 key (which I already have), a few other parameters (corpName, username, etc.).

I think I was following the technical documentation closely, but the response always tells me I'm using invalid signature.

I can't get much support from the CSOD side, nor do they seem to have a developer community. So I'm throwing this question here hoping some one have insight into this. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Any sample code you can share (without the keys) ? Not much information to go by above. Are you using C# to code this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you are having trouble with the API for the CSOD catalog and that you feel you did not get the proper support from Cornerstone.  The catalog web service is one of our most popular and clients get a lot of out of it.  I am the Manager of Integration Services and would be happy to help you realize this value as well.

There are a few different ways we can get this to work for you.  I can provide you a tool for generating the signature and you can compare the signature generated by the tool with the signature generated in code.  I can also review your .net code and confirm if it is correct. If the signature is correct and the service still receives an error in the response, then we can continue to dig deeper, but will need you to provide the request and response XML.

If you contact Cornerstone's Global Product Support line (contact info below) or your CSM and I am sure we can help you.

Local:  310-752-0191
Toll Free:  855-743-3415

Thank you and hope to hear from you soon.

Howard